# PHP copy is returning failed but creating a zero byte file - why?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm having trouble uploading an attachment from a webform, but it was working fine before.  Not sure what may have changed.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
    if ($_POST["send"] == "true")
 {
      $uploadedFile="";
     //upload attachment 
     if($_FILES['filename'])
     { 
         $file=$_FILES['filename'];
         if($file['size'] > 0)
         {

            $fileName = $file['name'];
            $tmpName  = $file['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $file['size'];
            $fileType = $file['type'];
            $uploadedFile=TEMP_UPLOAD_FOLDER."/".$fileName;

            //if(!move_uploaded_file($tmpName,$uploadedFile))
            if(!copy($tmpName,$uploadedFile)) {
                $msg .="Error uploading attachemnt to " . TEMP_UPLOAD_FOLDER ."/".$fileName . ". ";
            }

          }
     }  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact your host and check your disk space. Chances are that the disk space is full and thus the reason why the files are empty.

If you have ssh access, check disk space via:

```
df -h
```